# How does Node.js execute code when there are multiple users (example included)?

Tags: node.js

I'm a beginner with node.js and I'm trying to understand how Node.js executes code.

To test this, I created a simple application that does the following:

1. Users inputs "name" and "id" number into an html. This html makes a "post" request to my application.
2. Based on the input, the application generates a QR code that it shown as a base64 image on the following page (I rendered the page with pug).

My question is: Let's say there were 1 Million users who accessed the application at the same time, would Node.js still run the application for each user? I.e. that each user gets their own, unique generated QR code?

Code: This is where the POST request gets sent to. In the response, the image (called data) is sent as a base64 string:

```js
app.post('/generateQR', function (req, res) {
  var url = 'http://example.com/success.html';
  var urlString = `${url}?name=${validator.escape(
    req.body.name
  )}&id=${validator.escape(req.body.id)}`;
  generateqrcode(urlString).then((data) => {
    res.status(200).render('qr', {
      name: validator.escape(req.body.name),
      id: validator.escape(req.body.id),
      image: data,
    });
  });
});
```

This is the function that actually generates the QR code and returns "data" to the code snippet above.

```js
// Generate QR code
const generateqrcode = async (urlString) => {
  data = await qrcode.toDataURL(`${urlString}`);
  return data;
};
```

Thanks for an answer.

Comment: Yes, if you send _n_ requests to your web server, the application will run the callback for the relevant route the same number of times.

Comment: Node.js work in single-threaded environment. For your particular case it means all incoming requests will be queued and served one by one. More details here: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I was wondering. I read about the event loop before, but I wasn't sure whether there could be a case where the "order of requests" is changed. i.e. that for some reason user n+4 gets the generated QR code of user n+1.